# Find point and direction where the derivative of a function gets its maximum value

Tags: vector-spaces

Find those points and directions so that the directional derivative of $f(x,y)=3x^2+y^2$ gets its maximum value, while the point $(x,y)$ moves on $x^2+y^2=1$

Well, it's easy to show that the gradient vector of $f$ is $\nabla_f=<6x,2y>$
Then at a point $A(x_0,y_0)$ the required direction is $<6x_0,2y_0>$ and also the relation $x_0^2+y_0^2=1$ should stand true.

From this point forward how can I work to find $(x_0,y_0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\vec{u}$ is $\nabla f \cdot \vec{u}$. So in your case, it is
$$<6x_0, 2y_0>\cdot <x_0,y_0>=6x_0^2+2y_0^2$$

Now we know that $x_0^2+y_0^2=1$. We can then simplify the above expression using this fact. Can you continue from here?

Comment: At this point you should not use the derivative again, since there is restriction of the $x$ value, $-1\leq x\leq 1$. Within this range, what is the maximum value you can get?

Comment: They are written in terms of $x_0, y_0$ since you have to move on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$. The range of $x$ is again because it has to be on the circle. And on this circle the $x$ values are in this range.